# How to start vlc-nox via ssh in a Linux server running in text mode?

Tags: linux, ssh, vlc

***Background***
I have a Linux server running in text mode with no X installed. I intend to show video and image using directfb to the monitor (actually a TV). I have installed vlc-nox and it runs as expected if it is invoked in default console (physical keyboard).

***Issue***
When running it via SSH, no video is displayed, but audio is okay. The error is as below:

```
directfb vout display error: Cannot create primary surface
fb vout display error: cannot get terminal mode (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
core video output error: video output creation failed
core decoder error: failed to create video output
```

***fbi's way***
I think fbi also facing the same issue, as it would raise an error like below:
`ioctl VT_GETSTATE: Inappropriate ioctl for device (not a linux console?)`
But, fbi provides a solution for this case: `-T  -vt <arg>           start on virtual console <arg>`
So, `sudo fbi -T 1 /path/to/image/file` would display image as expected.

***Question***: What's the vlc's way?

Comment: I have found a way eventually and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally have a solution for this, so I post it here in case someone has the same question.

My understanding is that vlc needs to run under a real tty, not a pseudo tty. My solution is composed of two parts.

**Part 1**: Let vlc run as daemon mode.

1. Create a user for the daemon and assign audio and video privilege.

`#useradd -c "VLC daemon" -d / -G audio,video -M -p \! -r -s /bin/false -u 75 -U vlcd`

2. Run vlc at startup using tty1

I have tried this with unit under ubuntu.

```
[Unit]
Description=VLC server
After=network.target auditd.service
Conflicts=getty@tty1.service
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vlc -I rc --rc-host 127.0.0.1:8080
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure
RestartPreventExitStatus=255
User=vlcd
Type=simple
#StandardError=tty
StandardOutput=tty
StandardInput=tty
RemainAfterExit=yes 
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=vlc.service
```

Please take notic of the `Conflicts`, `ExecStart`, `StandardInput`, and `StandardOutput` parts.

- In `Conflicts`, it will bypass the default getty service, otherwise it should be disable manually by `#systemctrl disable getty@tty1`.
- In `ExecStart`, do not use the -d switch, which meaning that it would keep running and occupying VT 1, which is activated by <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>. `-rc` enables the remote connect interface.
- In `StandardInput/Output`, specify the `tty` as input and output device.

**Part 2**: Remote talk with the daemon, to let it play the file.

As `--rc-host` specify a local port, we need to ssh to the server first. Then, use telnet to interact (add, play, pause) with vlc.

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 8080
add /path/to/video/file
```